# Accessing nodes of networkx graph in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to access and store nodes of networkx graph and  then do further processing on it. I have following code:

```
for node in vis:    
    for a,b in G[node]:
        print a,b
```

This code gives following Error : 
    Traceback (most recent call last):[1]

```
  File "C:\Users\Mrinal\workspace\algo_asgn1\prims.py", line 29, in <module>
    for a,b in G[node]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

whereas when i write:

```
for node in vis:
        print G[node]
```

I get following output which I suppose is a dictionary with key as destination node and weight of the connection as value.

```
{2: {'weight': 5}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {'weight': 2}}
{2: {'weight': 5}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {'weight': 2}}
{2: {'weight': 5}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {'weight': 2}}
{2: {'weight': 5}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {'weight': 2}}
{2: {'weight': 5}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {'weight': 2}}
```

My graph has following data:

```
1 2 5
1 3 2
2 3 4
2 4 6
1 4 2
```

What mistake am I doing over here?
Can someone please suggest me changes.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show some example from vars `vis` and `sample`?

Comment: vis and sample both are set which has lets say '1'
I want to access 2,5 ; 3,2 ; 4,2 as in nodes which are connected to 1 and their weights

Comment: edited sample as vis both are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`G[node]` is a dictionary. [Iterating over a dictionary gives you the keys of that dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), which in this case are the integers `2,3,4`. Thus, if you run this snippet you get the following output:

```
>>> for a in {2: {'weight': 5}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {'weight': 2}}:
...     print a
... 
2
3
4
```

The problem you're having stems from the fact that you are trying to iterate over two variables -- `for a, b in x` -- where `x` is an integer and thus can't split into two separate variables. Instead, just use a single variable to get the node, e.g.

```
>>> node = {2: {'weight': 5}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {'weight': 2}}
>>> for a in node:
...     print a, node[a]
... 
2 {'weight': 5}
3 {'weight': 2}
4 {'weight': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong here that i did not use .iteritems()

```
for node in vis:    
    for a,b in G[node].iteritems():
        print a,b
```